# Elasticsearch treat nested json as plain string: can't get text on a start_object

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm trying to add some json documents elastic, which have deep nested json structure.

I'd like to treat some of those **nested fields** as **plain not-indexed `text` instead of json**  or **skip**, or them is it's not possible.

for example, I have `event` documents like this:

```
{
    "cluster": "production1",
    "header": {
        "os": "ios",
        "experiments": {
            "e1": {
                "field1": "value1",
                "field2": "value2"
                "array": ["id0"]
            },
            "e2": {
                "field3" : "value3",
                "array": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I want everything under `header.experiments` field be treated as one plain text.
I tried this mapping, but it does not work for me, because `experiments` field is object and not a string: `error: can't get text on a start_object`.

```
"mappings": {
    "event": {
      "properties": {
        "cluster": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true
        },
        "header": {
          "os": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": true
          },
          "experiments": {
            "type": "text",  // This does not work 
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**How can I make ElasticSearch treat sub-field as plain text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the field entirely you could set the `enabled` to `false` in the index mapping for the `experiments` field:

```
"mappings": {
  "event": {
    "properties": {
      "cluster": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": true
      },
      "header": {
        "os": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true
        },
        "experiments": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> The `enabled` setting, which can be applied only to the mapping type and to `object` fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the `_source` field, but it is not searchable or stored in any other way:

see this for details:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html